# Java MySQL Table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have two java processes namely Ticket Creation and Billing Daemon. Both of these processes use same MySQL Innodb Table "Billing". Ticket Creation mainly creates billing ticket and it includes inserts/update ticket of users.  Billing Daemon retrieves the ticket and then sends billing to users finally updating result (success/failure) to "Billing" Table. Each Day billing tickets are created for thousands of users and if billing is created today, it's called "New Ticket" and others created previously are called "Old Tickets".  The problem which I am facing is, both the Processes use same Table and Insert/Update Record is getting very slow.  Solution which I tried

```
1. Stopped billing while ticket creation: I got late to bill users and billing 
success rate got slow.
```

When both the processes are used, ticket creation got very slow  and billing were mostly sent for "Old Tickets" rather "New Tickets" where failure rate becomes high.

Please suggest, how can I come to solve this issue? Will creating Child and Master Table of "Billing" will solve? OR do I have to create another table? OR is there any appropriate solution?

```
Database is in Amazon RDS using MySQL Innodb. Please adivse urgently as 
my billing rate is getting really slow.
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to understand _why_ it is slow - profile the database and run EXPLAIN on your queries.  From the detail of your question we cannot tell if it's size or concurrent access that is the biggest problem.  It may simply be that adding indices to certain column(s) resolves your performance issues.

Comment: If size turns out to be the biggest problem then [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html) may be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often this is transaction throughput / concurrency problem. For instance when selecting and modifying the ticket, you need to consider how many objects you are locking and how long it takes. Because when this happen your update transaction will not run and wait until the locked resource is finished.

Fine tune your transaction, do not lock any more objects than you need. And if you do need to lock them make sure you release it as soon as possible.